# Sometimes Qt's paintGL does not draw an OpenGL edge of Bullet's Physics colliders

Tags: c++, qt, bulletphysics, qtopengl

It works 50 by 50%:

[image] [image]

I use a timer for redrawing:

```
void Widget::animationLoop()
{
    m_deltaTime = m_elapsedTimer.elapsed() / 1000.f;
    m_elapsedTimer.restart();
    m_pWorld->stepSimulation(m_deltaTime, 8);
    update();
}
```

I call collider's drawing (`m_pWorld->debugDrawWorld();`) like this:

```
void Widget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    m_pWorld->debugDrawWorld();

    m_projViewMatrix = m_projMatrix * m_viewMatrix;
    m_pPlayer->position = m_pPlayerCollider->getPosition();
    m_pPlayer->rotation = m_pPlayerCollider->getRotation();
    m_pPlayer->draw(m_projViewMatrix);
    m_pGround->draw(m_projViewMatrix);
    m_pPlatforms->draw(m_projViewMatrix);
}
```

I have the `DebugDrawer` class that I inherit from `btIDebugDraw`. I override the `drawLine` method to transform the 1x1x1 cube to make a segment to draw. I draw the segment by calling `m_pColliderEdge->draw(m_projViewMatrix);` in the `drawLine` method.

I tried to send a pointer to the QOpenGLWidget object to the `DebugDrawer` constructor:

```
DebugDrawer(QOpenGLWidget *widget, btDynamicsWorld *pWorld, ColliderEdge *pColliderEdge);
```

to keep it for `makeCurrent` but this did not help:

```
void DebugDrawer::drawLine(const btVector3 &from, const btVector3 &to, const btVector3 &color)
{
    /* ... */
    m_pWidget->makeCurrent();
    m_projViewMatrix = projMatrix * viewMatrix;
    m_pColliderEdge->draw(m_projViewMatrix);
}
```

Comment: I added more information (about trying of `makeCurrent`).

Comment: I added some information about a timer for redrawing.

Comment: Usually, this implies some sort of pointer problem.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget thank you! You set a direction for me. I forgot to get the `uMvpMatrix` location  in the `ColliderEdge` class. I will publish a simple example in the next time when I ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to get the uMvpMatrix location in the ColliderEdge class:

```cpp
ColliderEdge::ColliderEdge(QOpenGLShaderProgram *program,
                           const VertexBuffersData &vertexBuffers)
    : m_pProgram(program)
{
    m_vertPosBuffer = vertexBuffers.vertPosBuffer;
    m_amountOfVertices = vertexBuffers.amountOfVertices;

    m_pProgram->bind();
    m_aPositionLocation = m_pProgram->attributeLocation("aPosition");
    m_uMvpMatrixLocation = m_pProgram->uniformLocation("uMvpMatrix");
}
```

Sorry, guys. I will publish simple examples in the next time when I ask questions.

[image]